# Weak Refrence in class return nil when created in first class's init

Tags: ios, swift, reference, one-to-many, weak

im trying to create weak reference class in another class, in first class's init i create instance of second class to use it in a function, but after init function is done , second class get destroyed and return nil,
here's a example code

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class A {
    weak var b : B?
    init(){
        NSLog("a Created")
        self.b = B()
    
    }
    deinit{
        NSLog("a Destroyed")
    }
}

class B {
    var arrayOfA : Array <A> = []
    init(){
        NSLog("b Created")
       
    }
    deinit{
           NSLog("b Destroyed")
    }
    func printSomething(){
        NSLog("print Something")
    }
}


func test(){
    let a : A = A()
    a.b?.printSomething()
    NSLog("still in test()")
}

test()
```

in console i see this

> 2016-04-04 00:34:50.516 MyPlayground[20009:921709] a Created
>
> 2016-04-04 00:34:50.516 MyPlayground[20009:921709] b Created
>
> 2016-04-04 00:34:50.516 MyPlayground[20009:921709] b Destroyed
>
> 2016-04-04 00:34:50.527 MyPlayground[20009:921709] still in test()
>
> 2016-04-04 00:34:50.527 MyPlayground[20009:921709] a Destroyed

and calling printSomething() will return nil

i dont want create B class outside of A class and also i want it weak for memory leak problems.

some how i want one to many relationship between two swift class , so i can load data from function

Comment: An object is deallocated if there is no strong reference to it, so this is expected behavior. This looks like an XY-problem, what memory issues are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MartinR for example if i create A class without weak reference and in B class populate arrayOfA then when controller is dismissed i get memory leak. to fix this i should in viewController's deinit ,  empty arrayOfA and then assign nil to A class. this is not ideal way and sometimes it throws exeptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declare `b` as `weak`, it gets deallocated as soon as it goes out of scope.  In this case, as soon this code:

```
init(){
  NSLog("a Created")
  self.b = B()
}
```

finishes execution, `self.b` gets destroyed.  This is the expected behavior.  If you want `b` to hang around after the `init` then you should leave it as `strong`.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
func test(){
  let b : B = B()
  let a : A = A(b:b)
  a.b?.printSomething()
  NSLog("still in test()")
}
```

In `A` you can make a special `init` that takes in a `B`:

```
init(b: B){
  NSLog("a Created")
  self.b = b
}
```

With this code, `A`'s reference to `B` is still weak, but since the `B` is still around in the `test()` method, it's also there when `printSomething()` is called.